# How to show Arabic and English text on TextView on Android?

Tags: android, localization, textview, arabic

I have two unfocused `TextView` in the single layout. I want to show Arabic text on one `TextView` and English text on another `TextView`. I have use `values/strings.xml` for English and `values-ar/strings.xml` for Arabic text. My problem is Arabic text not showing in the `TextView`. If I change the custom locale to `ar` means its showing. How to show the Arabic text without changing the custom locale?

Comment: If you want to show the Arabic text irrespective of the locale then why are you storing it in a locale specific file (`values-ar/strings.xml`)?

Comment: Its not a single word or single paragraph. I have multiple categories and need to show for selected category.

Comment: Follow this helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) and enjoy! There is a complete description of problem and an algorithm as its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its default behaviour for Android. It will take locale information from system and map appropriate string resource from values-ar.
Text you want to show in Arabic you have to take entry in values/strings.xml and have to put those arabic character that you want to display.

please share the result when you tried this.

Comment: I will use `string.xml` for both English and Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

Put both arabic and english text in each `strings.xml`

Comment: Thanks Las. and its i know already. My problem is i have same list of category for english and arabic. So i use the category name as key. Also every category description is in big paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

To do this we need the font file for Arabic fonts. For example ,we have the Arabic font file name as arabicfont.ttf. Save this file into the assets folder then use the bellow code

```
arabicTextview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"arabicfont.ttf"));
arabicTextView.setText("ur text");
```

Like wise we can set any type of text with out using the Locale

Comment: first download the arabic font file from intetnet

Comment: arabicTextView.setText("ur text");   here for arabic text text will be written in english ?